# Tai Chi reference for beginner studying Chen style

Tags: training, technique, self-training, forms, tai-chi

I have just started learning Tai Chi as my first martial art. 
I’m following group lessons so the instructor cannot always follow everyone’s doing.

Could you please suggest a good book for a beginner studying Chen style tai chi? In particular I’m looking for a book on

1. philosophy, story, and theory
2. exercises and movement explained thoroughly

Comment: Welcome to the site, could you highlight what research you have already done (and why this was not adequate)? in its current form this question is likely to be closed for lack of prior research.

Comment: Sure! My teacher gave me some Italian video links and book resources but I do not like them, find them too personal and not broad enough. Looked for videos on YouTube and found something but my knowledge doesn’t let me understand if they are good or not (hence the looking for advice). Let me know if this is fine

Comment: We are still reading like we are expecting a list - I think there is enough information there to make a good question - recognising a good book from a bad one seems like a reasonable fit. Perhaps change the title to "How to recognise reputable resources on Tai-Chi philosophy?" - with most martial arts there are huge differences school to school (and instructor to instructor) so a good book for me might be a bad book for you - hence knowing *what* to look for is usually better than "which book/s"

Comment: Done! :) let me know if this looks good!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no prior research whatsoever and is asking for a long list of things which stack does not do.

Comment: Please... tell me what I should do to have your opinion on what’s the best resource for learning tai chi... why is there such a violence against someone asking for help? Also, looking here on SE for “Tai Chi Book” there is no result so... I think this is a pretty on topic question.

Comment: Please go read the [help] and take the [tour] to see how we work. We do not do multiple questions in one. We do not do long lists of things. "Best" is highly subjective and unlikely to yield any good results. If you wanted to learn how to recognise a reputable book, that would make a fine question. As it stands, your multiple questions are not a good fit.

Comment: May I create another question asking for “what is a good book for learning Tai Chi?” Would that be ok?

Comment: No, it would not be a good question: it is highly subjective and still asking for a list as there's no single book that covers all styles over all others. It would result in a popularity contest.

Comment: Well...fine... I’ll find another way. But let me tell you that, in the end, all questions here get a personal subjective response because there is a human behind the screen. Then other people add their own answer and other vote up or down, so all a popularity contest again... so I really do not see why, instead of losing time criticising my question, one could not answer: “this book is good for me, avoid that”.

Comment: If you have the time, dig into Youtube and look up Chen Zhenglei. He's one of the best. As for philosophy and written material, it's generally all not going to make any sense. Most of what is out there is junk, fluff that appeals to new-age types and those looking for some sort of spirituality. But to learn taiji, you need to learn from someone who knows internal mechanics and can make you feel it. It took my chen style instructor (a direct student of Chen Qingzhou) less than 10 minutes before I could feel and do p'eng jing in a dynamic way...

Comment: ... Whereas I had been doing yang and wu style for 2 years prior to that with other instructors, and thought I knew what it was about, but I was wrong. I had read all the nonsense fluff out there about it and managed to convince myself I knew it. Wrong. You don't begin to understand until you have someone show you. A good instructor can do that in just 10 minutes. Whereas getting with an instructor who doesn't know the first thing about it (99% of them) will only lead you to an exercise that looks like taiji. Good luck!

Comment: Check out my user profile and my answers, by the way. You'll find I've written some stuff about Taiji which you might find interesting... https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/users/1555/steve-weigand

Comment: This one for example: https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/6191/how-long-should-the-tai-chi-basic-24-form-take/6198#6198

Comment: Trying to suggest a book based only on the thin criteria of covering taiji is very difficult. Although the philosophy and theory may basically be the same, the way movements are performed between styles is not. Forms will not be the same, and significant elements like whether the body leans or remains upright may be different. Although you are not asking for a list of books, every book will equally meet the criteria, leading to a list from multiple answers. To be more helpful, you should at a minimum include what style of taiji you are learning and what forms if any are covered.

Comment: @mattm I’m learning Chen style. But thank you for at least politely explaining me why my question would have led to not satisfactory answer, I’m very grateful for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend *The Complete Book of Tai Chi Chuan* by Wong Kiew Kit. Take my advice with a grain of salt; although I studied tai chi for a couple years, I never made progress beyond the beginner stage.

From the back cover:

> It includes:
>
> - The history and development of various styles
> - The basic set of movements
> - The physical and mental benefits of Tai Chi Chuan
> - The relationship of Tai Chi to Taoism

The history of tai chi is debated. The Chinese martial arts tend to embellish their origin stories with elements of ancestors and the fantastic.

The usual caveats for martial arts book resources apply:

> It is not easy for beginners to learn any martial art from a book; it is even harder to learn internal arts like Tai Chi Chuan

The description of movements covers common fundamental movements and forms from multiple styles of tai chi, including a Chen style form. I don't know whether this will match what you are learning.

The study of tai chi is not for the short term:

> In my opinion, the practising Tomoi or Siamese Boxing is probably the fastest way one can learn to fight

In my personal opinion, the portions of the preface are most useful to understand the book's contents:

> Nevertheless, practising patiently does not mean following a method blindly. If a student who has patiently practised Tai Chi Chuan for many years still remains sickly, weak, or emotionally unstable or mentally dull, then he or she has not been judicious or wise. Such a person should either turn to something else, or seek more information from masters or books to improve his or her practice. Generally, people who have correctly practised an established method for a year should reap the benefits that method is reputed to bring.
>
> ...
>
> Although Tai Chi Chuan has a rich philosophy, usually recorded in poetic language, and some examples are found in this book, it is geared towards practical use in combat, and more significantly, in our daily life. In other words, if you have practised Tai Chi Chuan for 20 years, but cannot yet defend yourself when an assailant attacks you, or are still prone to anger or nervousness, or lack the energy to run and jump irrespective of how old you are, you have wasted your time. This book explains why and how Tai Chi Chuan enhances your health, work, and play.

Comment: Thank you @mattm (also for editing my question so professionally). I indeed go every week to Tai Chi class and practice home as often as I can, but I needed some kind of theoretic support. All this is great! Thank you